# How to capture complicated database transactions over multiple forms in Django

Tags: django, django-models

I need to capture some fairly complicated database changes from my users, including both updating and creating objects for multiple models.

I feel like the obvious way to do this would be by leveraging a sizeable amount of Javascript to create a JSON object containing all the necessary changes that can be POSTed in a single form. I am not keen on this approach as it prevents me from utilizing Django's `CreateView` and `UpdateView` classes, as well as the validation that comes with them. Also I am more comfortable in Python than Javascript.

I want to use a series of form POSTs to build up the necessary changes over time, but also need the transaction to be atomic, which, as far as I know, is not possible in Django. Another complication is that the models contain non-nullable fields and I would need to create objects before capturing the user input required to fill them. I do not want to make these fields nullable or use placeholders as this would make it more difficult to validate.

One approach I am considering is to create a duplicate of each of the necessary models to store partial objects. All fields would be nullable so the objects could be updated a bit at a time until all the forms have been POSTed. Objects in the original (main) model could then be created or updated to match the ones in the new (partial) model, which could then be deleted.

```
class Product(models.Model):
    field_a = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    field_b = models.PositiveIntegerField()

class PartialProduct(models.Model):
    field_a = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    field_b = models.PositiveIntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
```

The benefits of this approach as I see are:

- A multi-form approach, leveraging Django's model forms and related views as well as model validation.
- Not polluting the main models with incomplete objects.
- Enforcing fields not being null in the main models.

The potential drawbacks I can see are:

- Duplicating any changes to the main model in the partial model (the       approach is not DRY).
- It is a somewhat complicated approach (Simple is better than complex)

Are there any drawbacks to using this approach that I have not foreseen, or is there a better one I could use?

Comment: This approach did work, however maintaining the function that copies information between the models was a headache and I still feel there's a better solution I haven't found.